Flutter user filters in Firebase database streaming
I'm streaming from FirebaseFirestore, where a user has two options for filtering the data.
I have created a method for that logic, but I don't know which object data my method should take and as such I can't get the itemCount when I want to use the ListView.builder.
In my code, I've done the initialization as follows:
late String? selectedStatus;
 late List<String> status;
 late String? selectedOrder;
 late List<String> nameOrder;
 int selectedStatusIndex = -1;
 int selectedNameOrder = -1;

@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    status = [
      "Not Verified",
      "Pending verification",
      "Verified",
    ];
    selectedStatus = status[0];

    nameOrder = [
      "First Name",
      "Last Name",
    ];
    selectedOrder = nameOrder[0];
  }

String fieldName() {
    if (selectedOrder == nameOrder[1]) {
      return "FirstName";
    }
    if (selectedOrder == nameOrder[2]) {
      return "LastName";
    } else {
      return "";
    }
  }

Then in my method:
filter() {
    if (selectedStatus == status[0]) {
      if (selectedOrder == nameOrder[0]) {
        return FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection("collectionPath")
            .snapshots();
      } else {
        return FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection("collectionPath")
            .orderBy(
              fieldName(),
              descending: false,
            )
            .snapshots();
      }
    } else {
      if (selectedOrder == nameOrder[0]) {
        return FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection("collectionPath")
            .where("Status", isEqualTo: selectedStatus)
            .snapshots();
      } else {
        return FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection("collectionPath")
            .where("Status", isEqualTo: selectedStatus)
            .orderBy(
              fieldName(),
              descending: false,
            )
            .snapshots();
      }
    }
  }

In my build widget, I have a stream build where I called my filter() method in the stream.
StreamBuilder(
  stream: filter(),
  builder: (context, snapshot){
  return ListView.Builder(
      itemCount: //This is where the problem is 
      itemBuilder: .....
     )
   )

The problem is in the itemCount. I believe since my filter() does not take in any object, the stream builder does not understand it as a query from Firestore. But the problem is I don't which object FirebaseFirestore, and for that matter my filter() method should take.

Since you're using a StreamBuilder, so there's no need to nest a ListView.Builder in there. Instead use the normal ListView constructor with the children you get from the snapshots() stream.
Following the Flutter example from the Firebase documentation on listening to updates:
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
  stream: filter(),
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasError) {
      return const Text('Something went wrong');
    }

    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
      return const Text("Loading");
    }

    return ListView(
      children: snapshot.data!.docs
          .map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
            Map<String, dynamic> data =
                document.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>;
            return ListTile( // Render your document data here
              title: Text(data['full_name']),
              subtitle: Text(data['company']),
            );
          })
          .toList()
          .cast(),
    );
  },


Thank you very much but there is a little problem. When I call the snapshot.data!.docs.map...  the docs is red-underlined and says: 'docs' isn't defined for the type 'Object'
Also if I use the ListView,  how will I be able to get the number of items in the database, and also get the data of the selected item?

It looks like you didn't declare the type that filter() returns. It seems that that's a Stream<QuerySnapshot> so: Stream<QuerySnapshot> filter() { ... }.
The number of items in the QuerySnapshot is snapshot.docs.length iirc.
